# No pearl dragon - 15 pairings already

Tags: dragonvale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you breed a Pearl Dragon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71741/how-do-you-breed-a-pearl-dragon)

Getting really frustrated! Snow & Seaweed, Seaweed & Snow - 15 tries and NO pearl. I've moved stuff around, reversed pairings, tried a new pair ( all are level 10).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm up to ~40 attempts since June 3rd. Even got a Rainbow Dragon at some point. It just takes luck. =\

Comment: The correct answer is at [How do you breed a pearl Dragon]( http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71741/how-do-you-breed-a-pearl-dragon). It's quite rare, I've had....more than 15, probably closer to 40 like Fluttershy, but that is the correct pairing, another user on this site got it with Snow and Seaweed. I don't think there's any special trick; items/levels never seem to affect breeding chance